# Integrating Firebase to XCode

Tags: xcode, firebase, command, installation, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate Firebase to my app in XCode. In order to do so, I followed Firebase's website's commands step by step. However, when I typed in the pod init command in terminal, I got an error message saying -bash: pod: command not found so I searched and found that if I typed in sudo gem install cocoapods it would be all set.

After entering the command, it downloaded a lot of files without a problem. And it let me to enter the pod init command. After that a new pod file was created and all I have to do is now to enter the pod install command. However, when I enter pod install command, I get a really long process (provided below). I'm also watching a step-by-step video on linking Firebase to my XCode project but this step happens immediately there, without even connecting to a website. (or at least it doesn't show)

I would be very glad if someone can help me out as I don't want to do anything wrong after this step.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
$ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master -- progress
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 2377896, done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (175/175), done.        
91% (2171896/2377896), 396.03 MiB | 1.50 MiB/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes, or more depending on the network connection, is expected. CocoaPods requires installing the entire git repository of all existing CocoaPods podspecs. This can take awhile, especially on the first install. It's a known but tricky issue. See more details [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7046).